# MongoDB service not working on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-15.04

when I do this:

`sudo service mongodb start`,

I get this error message:

> Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No
>   such file or directory.

So, I did this: `mongod --version`

I get this:

```
 db version v2.6.3
 2015-12-14T11:28:06.867+0500 git version: nogitversion
 2015-12-14T11:28:06.867+0500 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

I check the mongod status,I get this message:

```
 mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 一 2015-12-14 11:18:19 ORAT; 5min ago
 Docs: man:mongod(1)
 Process: 17923 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf    (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 17923 (code=exited, status=100)
```

I have used all kinds of methods which I can searched, but they don't work. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run

> sudo service mongod start

not

> sudo service mongodb start

Ensure that you install your MongoDB correcly. Well formed installation instruction provided on [official MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) and on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Also verify that you correctly prepared mognodb to run, see [Run MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#run-mongodb) section on official site.